# Zend Framework optimization, tcpsndbuf & kmemsize

Tags: apache, zend-framework, apc

We're on the [mid-tier DV Rage server](http://mediatemple.net/webhosting/dv/pricing.php) on media temple using Zend Framework, and we've been getting QoS warnings in Virtuzzo pretty consistantly. We've spent the last week installing APC (tweaking that to death), mysql and apache tweaks (many recommended by Media Temple), front end gzip, `Zend_View` caching, and every optimization technique recommended in the Zend manual. At this point, I think we've gotten over our kmemsize issues mostly, but we are still getting tcpsndbuf warnings and I honestly don't know what to do with those. Our traffic is around 1000 uniques a day and I'm having a hard time believing that we can't support that. MT seems to be kind of "stingy" with the memory and after all this work optimizing, the answer seems to be "add more memory/upgrade"

1. Should we just stop "playing server" and start recommending *actual* dedicated servers for our clients?
2. Does anyone have any recommendations as to how much memory we need to be running a Zend Framework-based site...assuming our current of "1GB of dedicated RAM" (what it says in the marketing)?

I know this is a lot to ask, but we're at our wits end and we're more "code" than "server" people (so apologies in advance if any of this sounded stupid). :)

**Edit.** Ok, so of our 512MBs, (mt) has allocated 13MB to kmemsize. Is this ridiculously low? I feel like it is.

Comment: Although you've applied the most known ZF optimization , but i think your problem comes from MT , you may order 1 month of 1 GB RAM and monitor the  tcpsndbuf & kmemsize........ i am willing to know what is ur solution ???

Comment: definitely seems quite low. Normally those values are determined automatically during initial server configuration with the vzsplit utility. Checking on my company's current vps configs, our basic plan (which comes with 512mb) has a kmemsize barrier/limit of 60mb/120mb

Comment: @Mark I thought so. Plesk recommends 15-20% of the RAM allocated. We've got like 1-2%. Just not cutting it.

Comment: 13MB is very low in my experience working with a few different VPS providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: switch hosting.